# Use facebookpassport / node and react

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hello i m using facebook passport in my backend in node . Everything is fine i can log in and res.send the user. But in react i have no idea how to receive this user..

When i click on my button a popup open with the fb login page and send me to my callback url then the sent object is displayed on screen but how can i receive it in front / React if i dont do any call to it??

Here is my route

```
app.get('/api/user/auth/facebook/callback', (req, res, next) => {
    passport.authenticate('facebook', (err, user, info) => {
        if (err) return res.send(err);
        if (!user) {
            return res.send({ status: false, details: 'error occured' });
        } else {
            return res.send(user);
        }
    })(req, res, next)
})
```

Thank you for your help and if you need any explanations or code example just ask